# Android - how to animate a moving shape using custom SurfaceView?

Tags: android, graphics, 2d, surfaceview

I'm trying to draw shapes that will move around the screen using the LunarLander example as a base. The problem is that instead of 'moving' they just redraw in new position, while the old position is also still drawn. I've put together the shortest code I could to demonstrate the problem.

Main activity:

```
package ybz.test;

import ybz.fireworks.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "CL_FireworksActivity";
    MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            findViewById(R.id.btnStart).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.btnStop).setOnClickListener(this);

            mySurfaceView = (MySurfaceView) (findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to create; " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStart:
            try {
                mySurfaceView.startThread();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnStop:
            mySurfaceView.stopThread();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Custom SurfaceView:

```
package ybz.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Paint.Cap;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private DrawThread drawThread;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Point location;

    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Cap.SQUARE);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        location = new Point(0, 200);
    }

    public void startThread() {
        drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder(), this);
        drawThread.setRunning(true);
        drawThread.start();
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        drawThread.setRunning(false);
        drawThread.stop();
    }

    public void update() {
        location.x = location.x + 10;
        if(location.x > getWidth()) {
            location.x = 0;
        }
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(location.x, location.y, 15, paint);
    }

    class DrawThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;
        private boolean run = false;

        public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder,
                MySurfaceView mySurfaceView) {
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            this.mySurfaceView = mySurfaceView;
            run = false;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            this.run = run;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas canvas = null;
            while (run) {
                try {
                    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                        mySurfaceView.onDraw(canvas);
                        mySurfaceView.update();
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ybz.test.MySurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/lbl_start" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/lbl_stop" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the Surface view does not clear itself after each draw, so I need to do it explicitly.
A quote from [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#on-surfaceview):

> Note: On each pass you retrieve the Canvas from the SurfaceHolder, the
>   previous state of the Canvas will be retained. In order to properly
>   animate your graphics, you must re-paint the entire surface. For
>   example, you can clear the previous state of the Canvas by filling in
>   a color with drawColor() or setting a background image with
>   drawBitmap(). Otherwise, you will see traces of the drawings you
>   previously performed.

The onDraw() method is updated:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawCircle(location.x, location.y, 15, paint);
}
```

Comment: There is a way to clear the surface view canvas using `canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);` before draw

Answer (score -2):

You need to repaint the canvas with the background color at the beginning of the onDraw() method of the SurfaceView derived class.

Here are my three video tutorials which will help you understand Android Graphics & Animation completely. It explains how to develop Animation using both normal view and surface view.

https://youtu.be/kRqsoApOr9U

https://youtu.be/Ji84HJ85FIQ

https://youtu.be/U8igPoyrUf8